# Partial fraction decomposition - denominator to the power of 3

Tags: partial-fractions

How to get correct partial fraction decomposition of this expression?

$$\frac{3x+3y-z}{(x+y+z)^3}$$

Comment: this is what i have found $$3\, \left( x+y+z \right) ^{-2}-4\,{\frac {z}{ \left( x+y+z \right) ^{3
}}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{A}{x+y+z}+\frac{B}{(x+y+z)^2}+\frac{C}{(x+y+z)^3}$$

Now find $A,B,C$.

Comment: $\frac{A}{x+y+z} + \frac{B}{(x+y+z)^2} + \frac{B}{(x+y+z)^2} = \frac{3x+3y-z}{(x+y+z)^3}$

multiply both sides by $(x+y+z)^3$

$A(x+y+z)^2 + B(x+y+z) + C = 3x+3y-z$
$A(x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy +2xz +2yz) + Bx+By+Bz + C = 3x+3y-z$

compare both sides of equation
$A=0$,
$B= 3$ according to comparison $x$ and $y$ or $B= -1$  according to comparison with $z$, what about the C?

Comment: @Vid: what about $B=3$ and $C=-4z$?

Comment: I got it, thanks!